# How do i Change the default name that get's associated with a new Repository on Github in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, repository

Whenever I Share Project on Github there is usually a default name that gets associated with the repository. As shown below.

[image]

How do I change that name to a default name that I want, either on android studio or anywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by running doing running following on the terminal

```
git config --global user.email "<new_email>" 
git config --global user.name "<new_name>"
```

and voila!